# ionic tab doesn't show correctlly

Tags: ionic-framework

I use the codes as following to jump to "account" if the user is logined:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
    if (is_login) {
        $state.go('account');
    }
})
```

But the content was covered by the header.

[But the content was covered by the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Okuh.png)

Comment: can i see login.html page?

Comment: this is the login.html:
<ion-view view-title="Login">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
            </label>......

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<ion-header-bar>` instead of `<ion-nav-bar>` you might need to use `class="has-header"` because this way ionic does not arranges ion content tags content automatically. Also do not forget to initialize the ngApp in your javascript code. Also as I experienced before javascript errors might cause the problem as well, check for errors. Here is an example for above: http://jsbin.com/pagacohovohe/1/edit?html,js,output